# Spring boot autoconfiguration @ConditionalOnBean behaving weirdly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am writing a spring boot library that creates an autoconfiguration class conditionally if a specific bean is present.
The weird thing that is happening is in Conditions Evaluation Report, I see two entries for the same bean, highlighted below. Has someone else also faced similar issue ? How can I resolve this ? I tried reordering the library that was causing this.

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

MyTestConfguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.onkaar.test.Security SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.onkaar.test.Security (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (com.onkaar.xyz-property) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.onkaar.test.Security; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'testSecurity' (OnBeanCondition)
```

My concern is that if the same bean is showing in "Matched"; then why is it also showing up in "Did not match" section and due to which this autoconfiguration class not getting created.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can search your code to check whether there is Bean : com.onkaar.test.Security,  and then you will know the result.

Comment: Can you provide the annotations present on `MyTestConfguration`?

Comment: @Knox , we were using ComponentScan in the configuration class, that caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we were using annotation @ComponentScan in the configuration class which was causing this issue.
After removing this annotation, the issue is resolved.

Am still curious to understand how @ComponentScan can cause this.